# OnReceivedSSLError not for SDK version 4

Tags: android

Recently I updated my machine thus all my DEV environment got updated with latest Eclipse and Android SDK.   After hours of struggling to get my apps working in the simulator I got with a "WebView" client issue where it started giving my "Object moved to here" which suggests that it is a SSL error on URL redirection.  So I added OnReceivedSSLError event handler.  Now I cannot compile the project as it is asking me to change my minSDKVersion to 8 i.e. Android 2.2.

I want to build my app so that can be used on phones with SDK version 1.6 and higher.  I have 500+ customers that are currently using my app that are on Android 1.6.

So if I add this event will I loose v1.6 customers and if I don't then will my customers with higher Android versions will get this SSL error?

Please advise.